# How to upload file using Selenium WebDriver? (not work send_keys)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, selenium-chromedriver

I tried file upload using Selenium WebDriver (Python), but I can't upload it.
I want to upload the file to this website.
https://iotcube.net/process/type/wf1
But, when I tried sending a file using 'send_keys', it not worked.

I run that code in Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('my-awesome-dropzone').send_keys('FilePath')
```

How can I send file to that website? Help me.

Comment: It's windows base pop . it won't be handling by selenium .. you can try AutoIT for this operation

Comment: In Python biding only exists `send_keys`-method. There are no `sendKeys`.

Answer (score 0):

if its a window based file handling then selenium alone wont workout. You have to either use AutoIT or ROBOT.

[Can have a look at this](https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html)